# Tensorflow Prune Layer Not Supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pruning

I am trying to prune a model in tensorflow but coming across an error I don't know how to tackle. The error is `ValueError: Please initialize "Prune" with a supported layer. Layers should either be a "PrunableLayer" instance, or should be supported by the PruneRegistry. You passed: <class 'base_transformer_tf.TransformerEncoder'>`

The model is created using following

```
def transformer_encoder(num_columns, num_labels, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, window_size, dropout_rate, weight_decay, label_smoothing, learning_rate):
    
    inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (window_size, num_columns))
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(inp)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Activation('swish')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D(dropout_rate)(x)
    x = TransformerEncoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, window_size, dropout_rate)(x)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_labels, activation = 'sigmoid', dtype=tf.float32)(x[:, -1, :])
    
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = inp, outputs = out)
    model.compile(optimizer = tfa.optimizers.AdamW(weight_decay = weight_decay, learning_rate = learning_rate),
                  loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(label_smoothing = label_smoothing), 
                  metrics = tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name = 'AUC'), 
                  )
    
    return model
```

The pruning portion of code is following

```
pruning_params = {
      'pruning_schedule': tfmot.sparsity.keras.PolynomialDecay(initial_sparsity=0.00,
                                                               final_sparsity=0.50,
                                                               begin_step=0,
                                                               end_step=end_step)
}
model_for_pruning = prune_low_magnitude(model, **pruning_params)

# `prune_low_magnitude` requires a recompile.
model_for_pruning.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

logdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
callbacks = [
  tfmot.sparsity.keras.UpdatePruningStep(),
  tfmot.sparsity.keras.PruningSummaries(log_dir=logdir),
]
model_for_pruning.fit(np.concatenate((X_tr2, X_val)), np.concatenate((y_tr2, y_val)),
                  batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=validation_split,
                  callbacks=callbacks)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow does not know how to prune your custom `TransformerEncoder` Keras layer. You should specify which weights to sparsify, as in this example: [Prune custom Keras layer or modify parts of layer to prune](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/comprehensive_guide#prune_custom_keras_layer_or_modify_parts_of_layer_to_prune).

That would look like:

```
class TransformerEncoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer, tfmot.sparsity.keras.PrunableLayer):
  def get_prunable_weights(self):
    return [self.my_weight, ..]
```